# Predefined and stable arguments for \NewDocumentCommand

Tags: macros

I programed a `\NewDocumentCommand` which produces vertical bars for each of which the *numeric value* and *label text* are mandatory and *color* as optional argument. There are also some global parameter (`\startpoint`, `\scalingfactor`, `\bardistance`, `\barwidth` etc.)  that have to be specified prior to using the `\vbarchart` command (see MWE). This works well. However, I would like to know if someone has an idea how these "pre-parameters" can be prompted in a more inclusive way? Maybe producing a new environment and make them as prespecified options. The current way I would always have to copy these parameters to the section where I want to use the `\vbarchart` which is ok, but might be done better. Appreciate any help.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usetikzlibrary{math}

\NewDocumentCommand{\vbarchart}{m m O{black!5}}{
    \tikzstyle{label1} = [align=center, above,pos=0.5]
    \tikzstyle{label2} = [align=center, below,yshift=-3pt]

    \draw[fill=#3] (\startpoint,0) --++(0,{#1*\scalingfactor}) --coordinate[pos=0.5](b1) node[label1,font=\percsize]{\pgfmathprintnumber[use comma]{#1}\Barunit} ++(\barwidth,0) -- ++(0,{-#1*\scalingfactor})coordinate(r1);

    \tikzmath{\startpoint=\startpoint+\bardistance+\barwidth;}
    \coordinate(h)(0,0);
    \node[label2,font=\labelsize] at (h-|b1){#2};
    \draw (-0.25,0) -- ([xshift=0.25cm]r1);
}


\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzmath{\startpoint=0;}
\tikzmath{\scalingfactor=0.25;}
\tikzmath{\bardistance=0.5;}
\tikzmath{\barwidth=1;}
\newcommand{\percsize}{\normalsize}
\newcommand{\labelsize}{\normalsize}
\newcommand{\Barunit}{\%}

\vbarchart{20}{Bar\\ One}
\vbarchart{5}{Bar\\ One}[red]
\vbarchart{15}{Bar\\ Two}
\vbarchart{5}{Bar\\ One}[blue]
\end{tikzpicture}   
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can define those constants in the preamble, where you define `\vbarchart`, or you can define them _in_ the definition of `\vbarchart`...

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a job for `pgfkeys` (see the Section *Key management* in the pgf manual). You can initialise keys with `\pgfqkeys` (or `\pgfkeys`) and then set the keys with the optional argument `#3` to `\vbarchart` using a `key1=value1,key2=value2,...` syntax. I've marked my edits with comments in the code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{pgfkeys} % Load the package
\usetikzlibrary{math}

\NewDocumentCommand{\vbarchart}{m m O{}}{
    \pgfqkeys{/vbarchart}{% Define your keys - locally so that reset on every call of \vbarchart.
        barfill/.initial=black!5,
        percsize/.initial=\normalsize,
        labelsize/.initial=\normalsize,
        barunit/.initial=\%
    }
    \pgfqkeys{/vbarchart}{#3}% Set your keys according to the optional argument.
    \tikzstyle{label1} = [align=center, above,pos=0.5]
    \tikzstyle{label2} = [align=center, below,yshift=-3pt]

    % Then use the keys with \pgfkeysvalueof{/vbarchart/key}
    \draw[fill=\pgfkeysvalueof{/vbarchart/barfill}] (\startpoint,0) --++(0,{#1*\scalingfactor}) --coordinate[pos=0.5](b1) node[label1,font=\pgfkeysvalueof{/vbarchart/percsize}]{\pgfmathprintnumber[use comma]{#1}\pgfkeysvalueof{/vbarchart/barunit}} ++(\barwidth,0) -- ++(0,{-#1*\scalingfactor})coordinate(r1);

    \tikzmath{\startpoint=\startpoint+\bardistance+\barwidth;}
    \coordinate(h)(0,0);
    \node[label2,font=\pgfkeysvalueof{/vbarchart/labelsize}] at (h-|b1){#2};
    \draw (-0.25,0) -- ([xshift=0.25cm]r1);
}


\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzmath{\startpoint=0;}
\tikzmath{\scalingfactor=0.25;}
\tikzmath{\bardistance=0.5;}
\tikzmath{\barwidth=1;}

\vbarchart{20}{Bar\\ One}[barunit=$\mu$,percsize=\huge]
\vbarchart{5}{Bar\\ One}[barfill=red]
\vbarchart{15}{Bar\\ Two}[labelsize=\footnotesize,percsize=\footnotesize]
\vbarchart{5}{Bar\\ One}[barfill=blue]
\end{tikzpicture}   
\end{document}
```

[image: vbarchart]

Comment: Thx Felix that was the missing link I needed. :)

Answer (score 0):

Based on Felix awnser I found the ultimate solution to my initial question. I used the `pgfkeys` logic and included them within a `\NewDocumentEnvironment`. This way I can now enter the needed values that are to be specified differently from the defaults and I don't have to copy the "constant definitions" everytime I want to draw a barchart. They are now just to be entered in the environment definition if needed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,shapes.geometric,arrows,fit,positioning,arrows.meta,angles,quotes,decorations.pathmorphing,decorations.shapes,decorations.text,calc,math}


\NewDocumentCommand{\vbarchart}{m m O{black!5}}{
    \tikzstyle{label1} = [align=center, above,pos=0.5]
    \tikzstyle{label2} = [align=center, below,yshift=-3pt]

    \draw[fill=#3] (\startpoint,0) --++(0,{#1*\scalingfactor}) --coordinate[pos=0.5](b1) node[label1,font=\percsize]{\pgfmathprintnumber[use comma]{#1}\Barunit} ++(\barwidth,0) -- ++(0,{-#1*\scalingfactor})coordinate(r1);

    \tikzmath{\startpoint=\startpoint+\bardistance+\barwidth;}
    \coordinate(h)(0,0);
    \node[label2,font=\labelsize] at (h-|b1){#2};
    \draw (-0.25,0) -- ([xshift=0.25cm]r1);
}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{barchartenv}{O{}}
{\pgfqkeys{/barchartenv}{
        scale/.initial=0.1,
        bardis/.initial=0.75,
        barwidth/.initial=0.75,
        percsize/.initial=\normalsize,
        labelsize/.initial=\normalsize,
        barunit/.initial=\%}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \pgfqkeys{/barchartenv}{#1}
    \tikzmath{\startpoint=0;}
    \tikzmath{\scalingfactor=\pgfkeysvalueof{/barchartenv/scale};}
    \tikzmath{\bardistance=\pgfkeysvalueof{/barchartenv/bardis};}
    \tikzmath{\barwidth=\pgfkeysvalueof{/barchartenv/barwidth};}
    \newcommand{\percsize}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/barchartenv/percsize}}
    \newcommand{\labelsize}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/barchartenv/labelsize}}
    \newcommand{\Barunit}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/barchartenv/barunit}}}
{\end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}

\begin{barchartenv}[scale=0.1,bardis=1,barwidth=1,percsize=\small,labelsize=\large,barunit={} Awnsers]
\vbarchart{25}{One}
\vbarchart{5}{Two}[red!50]
\vbarchart{20}{Three}
\vbarchart{35}{Four}[blue!50]

\end{barchartenv}

\end{document}
```